# How to get only the "project name" from GCP using gcloud command?

Tags: bash, awk, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to get the project name of my GCP project.
Firstly, I tried using the command:

```
gcloud projects describe $PROJECT_ID
```

Here you get the poject Id, number name, Organization and other details.

Then next use `grep` command to get the project Name.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input (i.e. the output of `gcloud projects describe $PROJECT_ID`) and the expected output of the command you want to write given that input plus what you've tried so far, See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: @EdMorton - This question is about a Google Cloud specific command. IMHO he has met the requirements.

Comment: @JohnHanley the OP tagged the question with bash and awk so he is apparently looking for bash and awk commands, not sure why you removed those tags.

Comment: @EdMorton - As you know, one of the purposes of Stack Overflow is the sharing of knowledge. I removed those tags because the primary question is about a GCP command. Bash and Awk are side effects and may limit other options which might be better solutions. There are many ways to skin a cat and if we only limit answers to the exact question asked, most of Stack Overflow would be deleted to meet that criteria. As a Google GDE and an expert with these GCP tags, I am trying to improve the quality of answers by removing arbitrary limitations.

Comment: That's fine, the OP can always add the bash and/or awk tags back if they want help with either of those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's often more convenient to use `gcloud` only:

```sh
PROJECT=[[YOUR-PROJECT]]
gcloud projects describe ${PROJECT} \
--format="value(name)"
```

You may use e.g. `value(projectNumber)` to get the project number.

Answer (score 1):

To get the project name of your GCP project, use the below command:

```
gcloud projects describe $PROJECT_ID | grep name | awk -F'name: ' '{print $2}'
```

where, `$PROJECT_ID` is the `id` of your GCP project

Comment: No, that is NEVER the right approach. Please stop asking partial questions and posting your own answers immediately - ask better questions and listen to the advice you get.

Comment: @EdMorton - Creating a question and posting your own answer is perfectly fine on Stack Overflow and is encouraged. I agree that it might not be the best method, but we use votes and comments to manage this. A poor answer (in one person's opinion)  might be a good answer when viewed differently. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: it is in general BUT the OP has a history of posting partial questions and poor answers and not taking the advice of others in the forum. It's not my opinion - this is a poor answer because a) the OP is using an unquoted variable, b) the OP is piping grep to awk, and c) the OP should almost certainly be using `jq` or something else anyway.

Comment: @EdMorton - I did not review the quality of the poster, just how the question might benefit the community in the future. Thank you for this viewpoint.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the feedback. I will take this suggestion and improve. Actually, I am new to this bash and awk. I had also tried to search how to get project name in GCP and was unsuccessful. So, I tried to answer the question that I posted so that it will be helpful to others. I am currently working on `terraform` which needs the project name and using this to create a vpc name. I am calling the shell script file wherein I am passing the `gcloud` command. Anyways, sorry for the inconvenience caused.
Thanks for the help!